# How to avoid exponential conversion from unix to excel

Tags: scripting

I am generating a csv file in unix by calling database view.
After generating the file,I am sending the file to business users through email.
so the problem is when they open the cvs, big numbers values are reflecting with exponential number 1.05501E+17 instead of the actual number 105501060000700000.

Is there any way to avoid this or to fix this in unix.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes,didn't work.

Comment: Actual values are like this one 105501060000700000..

Comment: I got the solution.

Comment: @steve `"=""1000000000000000000000"""` imports as a string on my machine so I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `"=""` before the number and `"""` after, Excel should import as string, thus avoiding the exponential woe.

Instead of the original value of

```
105501060000700000
```

Add the extra characters, becoming as below, to import as string.

```
"=""105501060000700000"""
```